# Linq to SQL - Inserting entities with many to many relation

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Consider the following tables (screenshot of dbml file editor in Visual Studio):

http://roosteronacid.com/dbml.png

The *IngredientsRecipesRelation* table is a many-to-many table, linking *n* ingredients to a single recipe.

How would you insert the following recipe...:

```
Recipe { Name = "Dough" }
```

With the following ingredients...:

```
Ingredient { Name = "water", Unit = "cups", Amount = 2.0 },
Ingredient { Name = "flour", Unit = "cups", Amount = 6.0 },
Ingredient { Name = "salt", Unit = "teaspoon", Amount = 2.0 }
```

... Into the database?

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think many to many relations are supported in Linq 2 SQL.

Comment: @azamsharp - not directly, but you can use two one-to-many relations to get the same effect.

Comment: Your image is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the recipes and ingredients, then for each ingredient, create a relation associated with the ingredient.  Add each of these relations to the recipe and insert the recipe into the database.

```
var recipe = new Recipe { Name = "Dough" };

var ingredients = new []
{ 
   new Ingredient { Name = "water", Unit = "cups", Amount = 2.0 }, 
   new Ingredient { Name = "flour", Unit = "cups", Amount = 6.0 }, 
   new Ingredient { Name = "salt", Unit = "teaspoon", Amount = 2.0 }
};

foreach (var ingredient in ingredients)
{
   var relation = new IngredientsRecipesRelations();

   relation.Ingredient = ingredient;

   recipe.IngredientsRecipesRelations.Add(relation);
}

DataContext.Recipes.InsertOnSubmit(recipe);
DataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Note that you could add a partial class implementations with methods to hide this behavior from the class that uses it.  You'd want to make the associations internally scoped then expose some public methods to add/remove ingredients that work with the internal association as I've demonstrated above.

Answer (score 0):

azamsharp is correct in that it does not support many to many, however this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/mitsu/archive/2007/06/21/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-using-linq-to-sql.aspx) goes some way to show how it can be done, essentially you will be hand crafting some of the code